# Can't access file from seperate assembly?

Tags: c#, .net

I have two projects in my solution. One represents the main project and another one has the name of the first project but adds ".API" at the end, which acts as an assembly for my interfaces.

Since I use an interface for specific classes, I access the interface and not the actual concrete class, this brings a problem when I was to access a file from the main assembly inside a file in the main assembly and that's fine, the problem comes as I need to mention it in the interface file.

Otherwise it wouldn't be accessible as the interface file is our class in this example.

Here is a code example...

```
namespace App.Classes
{
    public class User : IUser 
    {
        public SomeType SomeType { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace App.Classes
{
    public enum SomeType
    {
        SpecialType,
        GoldType,
        SilverType,
        Other
    }
}

namespace App.API
{
    public interface IUser
    {
        public SomeType SomeType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The error I am receiving is `the type or namespace name 'SomeType' could not be found`.

When trying to add
`using App` to the interface file I receive an error telling me that namespace doesn't exist.

Primary assembly name: `App`
API assembly name: `App.API`

Comment: Are you really talking about [assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)? It sounds like you're not and it's really confusing me. Which part of the code you posted is in which file? If the namespace is `App.Classes`, why are you adding `using App` instead of `using App.Classes`? `using` directives are related to namespaces, not assemblies.

Comment: App depends on App.API. App.API cannot depend on App because that would be circular. You need to move enum SomeType into the App.API project.

Comment: can i assume you are referencing dll(namespace) and consuming with use of 'using'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly,

You have referenced your API (`App.API`), from you main app (`App`).

You are then trying to call/reference `SomeType` in your *API* which actually located back in (`App`).

Basically this (if it could be done) is called a [Circular Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference) for which .*Net* disallows.

Further more

> The type or namespace name 'SomeType' could not be found

This error is entirely appropriate, because there is no reference (even check your *API* project) from the `App.API` project to `App`. I know its not there because it cant be done, .Net wont let you. Ergo *Circular Reference*

You need to make common things common, i.e If your *API* needs to know about  `SomeType` it has to be placed in your *API* assembly (or a more common assembly that both `App` and `App.API` can reference).

The simple solution is to put `SomeType` back into `App.API` (the project, not just the namespace)

```
namespace App.API.Enums
{
    public enum SomeType
    {
        SpecialType,
        GoldType,
        SilverType,
        Other
    }
}
```

Or to create a 3rd assembly and reference it from both the `App` and `App.Api` projects